# Literal string interpolation - limit scope?

Tags: python, python-3.6, string-interpolation

Is it possible to limit scope of what literal string interpolation can get access to?

For example:

```
A = 10
B = 20
allowed_dict = {'a': 't1', 'b': 't2'}
```

I want to allow specific string evaluation to only have access to `allowed_dict` variable, but nothing else.

If string is in same scope, it can reach all those variables, like:

```
f'{A} {B} {allowed_dict}'
```

With `''.format`, you pass explicit kwargs, so only those values can be accessed. Is something similar available with `f''`?

P.S. Reasoning I am asking this, is that I want to use `f''`, to execute functions on the fly through some variables. E.g. `f'{my_func(1, 2)}'`. I guess this is not possible with `''.format` (to specify functions execution directly via string)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the use case where the scope becomes a problem. Can you make that clearer? Or provide a specific example that gives you the problem?

Comment: @ritlew for example, you allow to execute some functions via string interpolation. But in scope there are functions that are not intended for public use. If scope would not be limited, user could execute anything that is in scope (though via public API, user can only reach function that allows to run string interpolation). But maybe I'm overthinking here?:)

Comment: It doesn't sound like thats string formatting specific. It sounds like you're looking for a way to limit scope of variables/function in general. Is that right?

Comment: Well I care that scope would be limited when string will be executed. Because it would be exposed to more stuff than it needs to. Imagine that string is entered via input. So user could technically do more stuff than it is intended

Comment: No, there isn't I'm pretty sure. But this seems like a higher order issue. You have control over the namespace the string is used in. Also, a user cannot input an f-string

Comment: ". Reasoning I am asking this, is that I want to use f'', to execute functions on the fly through some variables" frankly, this sounds like the X-Y problem to me. Can you elaborate a little more on exactly what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: As I said, want to execute functions via str interpilation. Though maybe im overthinking as you said. Basically I was asking for string format functionality with function execution